# HighCharts Drilldown - colorByPoint

Tags: jquery, highcharts

What I am doing is asynchronously adding drilldown series using `addSeriesAsDrilldown`, but I am not to be able to enable `colorByPoint` for whichever drilldown series I choose. Is there a way to do this? The API documentation for HighCharts is a little obnoxious to navigate and find an answer.

I've tried Google searching it but, it doesn't seem anyone else has had the question.

I'm not sure a code snippet is really required, since it's just a general question. But if you need something, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've somewhat figured this out myself after a little bit of tinkering. It looks as though you can set the `colorByPoint` option dynamically through the plots option like so:

`chart.options.plotOptions.column.colorByPoint = true`

Interchanging "column" for whatever type of chart you want. So what I am doing is just setting the option dynamically after I receive the data back from the controller. Hopefully this helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above answer, just changed from:

```
chart.options.plotOptions.column.colorByPoint = true
```

to

```
chart.options.plotOptions.series.colorByPoint = true
```

and works for any type of chart